# why g++ -MM option ignore current work dir's include file

Tags: c++

Think the following example

```
myproj/
    main.cc
    test.h
```

main.cc simple include test.h with

```
#include "myproj/test.h"
```

where I run g++ **-MM** and **-M** in the same dir of myproj, I get

```
$ g++ -MM myproj/main.cc
main.o: myproj/main.cc
$ g++ -M myproj/main.cc
main.o: myproj/main.cc /usr/include/stdc-predef.h myproj/test.h
```

you will see that **-MM** option ignore the header **myproj/test.h**

The Question is myproj/test.h is not the system header, why  **-MM** option ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In include you specify path to header relatively the current source file(`main.cc` in your case). You need just

```
#include "test.h"
```

Comment: I know it works. But I want  to know the season why MM ignore test.h, It is strange that MM should only ignore system headers

Comment: @Chen Kaien When you do not specify MM flag gcc search headers in system header directories. I think, it Include the directory from which you run the compiler. Therefore gcc finds out your header by relative path from current directory.

Comment: Unless you intend to raise a bug on gcc, I wouldn't worry about it - just chalk it down as "one of those things", and change your `#include "myproj/..."` into `#include "..."` with `-I myproj` added to the compiler obtions.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm going to use -M instead of -MM option in my project which will cause the .d file become bigger